# Restricting work item state transitions to specific users

Tags: xml, azure, tfs, tfs-workitem

I want to restrict some transactions to specific users. Specifically, I want to enable only specific group users (Administrators \ Contributors) to enable WIT TRANSITION “A” to “B”.

I tried to follow [these instructions](http://www.codewrecks.com/blog/index.php/2011/09/19/deep-dive-in-process-templates-states-and-transitions). However, the following error is being produced when I’m trying to load the new WIT:

> `Error importing work item type definition:`
>
> `The 'for' attribute is invalid - The value '[Project Name]Project Administrators' is invalid according to its datatype 'http://schemas.microsoft.com/VisualStudio/2008/workitemtracking/typelib:IdentityName'- The Pattern constraint failed.`

My WITD XML is as follows:

```
<TRANSITION from="Integrated" to="Closed" for="[Project Name]Project Administrators">
    <REASONS>
        <DEFAULTREASON value="Verified Pass" />
    </REASONS>
    <FIELDS>
        <FIELD refname="Microsoft.VSTS.Common.ClosedDate">
            <SERVERDEFAULT from="clock" />
        </FIELD>
        <FIELD refname="Microsoft.VSTS.Common.ClosedBy">
            <ALLOWEXISTINGVALUE />
            <COPY from="currentuser" />
            <VALIDUSER />
        </FIELD>
    </FIELDS>
</TRANSITION>
```

Comment: Can you please show the XML for the transition?

Comment: Hi DaveShaw, 
<TRANSITION from="Integrated" to="Closed" for="[Project Name]Project Administrators">
          <REASONS>
            <DEFAULTREASON value="Verified Pass" />
          </REASONS>
          <FIELDS>
            <FIELD refname="Microsoft.VSTS.Common.ClosedDate">
              <SERVERDEFAULT from="clock" />
            </FIELD>
            <FIELD refname="Microsoft.VSTS.Common.ClosedBy">
              <ALLOWEXISTINGVALUE />
              <COPY from="currentuser" />
              <VALIDUSER />
            </FIELD>
          </FIELDS>
        </TRANSITION>

Comment: Got it, also, updated your XML into your question.

Comment: Unlike forum sites, we don't use "Thanks", or "Any help appreciated", or signatures on [so]. See "[Should 'Hi', 'thanks,' taglines, and salutations be removed from posts?](http://meta.stackexchange.com/questions/2950/should-hi-thanks-taglines-and-salutations-be-removed-from-posts).

Answer (score 1):

You need to use the term `[Project]` to represent the current team project for the work item, and a `\` to separate it from the Team Project Group:

```
<TRANSITION from="Integrated" to="Closed" for="[Project]\Project Administrators">
    <!-- Stuff -->
</TRANSITION>
```

Answer (score 0):

Example from MSDN:
http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/ms194981.aspx#Transitions

```
<TRANSITION from="Closed" to="Active"
     for="[Project]\Testers"
      not="[Project]\Developers">
    . . .
</TRANSITION>
```

See also:
[http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/aa337653(v=vs.110).aspx](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/aa337653%28v=vs.110%29.aspx)